# how to print two array variables in a line in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, printf

I tried this code in my shell script in ubuntu 12.04 bash

```
IFS=$'\t'
name=(one two three four five)
fam=($(seq -s" " 1 1 5))
for (i=0;i<5;i++) 
do 
  printf "%s\t%s\n" ${fam[i]} ${name[i]} 
done
```

The output I want is like that

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
```

But the really output is

```
1 2 3 4 5   one
two 
three   
four    
five
```

What went wrong in my code? and how to print more than one array variable in a line just using one loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
name=(one two three four five)
fam=(1 2 3 4 5)

for i in ${!name[*]}
do
  printf '%s %s\n' ${fam[i]} ${name[i]}
done
```

or you can just fix

```
for  (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
for ((i = 0; i < 5; i++))
```

Comment: Because if I want to get a big sequence like 10000,it is not a good way input all numbers by keyboard?What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

When you set IFS to '\t' it causes the array initializer to break the input on tabs so you get '1 2 3 4 5' assigned to fam[0]. You need to change the seq delimiter to match.

```
fam=($(seq -s $'\t' 1 1 5))
```